# Select Percentage of rows in Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

Is there a function to select the rows in data frame based on percentage.

For example, select first 25 % of rows, then the 50 % after and then finally the final 25%

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Functions `head(x, n)` and `tail(x, n)` yield first and last `n` rows of data frame `x`. Setting `n = ceiling( nrow(x)*percent/100)` allows to get first and last percents of rows:

```
head_percent <- function(x, percent) {
   # need validation of input x and percent!! 
   head(x, ceiling( nrow(x)*percent/100)) 
}

# last percent of a dataframe
tail_percent <- function(x, percent) {
   # need validation of input x and percent!! 
   tail(x, ceiling( nrow(x)*percent/100)) 
}
```

Subsetting a data frame also allows to obtain different percents:

```
subset_percent <- function(x, start=0, end=100) {
   stopifnot(
      is.numeric(start), is.numeric(end),
      start < end, start >= 0, end <= 100
   )
   nr <- nrow(x)
   rows <- 1:nr
   srt <- ceiling(start*nr/100)
   end <-floor(end*nr/100)
   x[srt:end,]
}

# Example
mydf <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(200), col2 = 1:200, 
                    col3 = rep(letters[1:2],100)) 
# Dividing mydf   
 subset_percent(mydf, 0, 25)
 subset_percent(mydf, 25.1, 75)
 subset_percent(mydf, 75.1, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr` you can use `slice`and `nrow()`:

```
# the first 25%:
iris %>%
  slice(1:round(nrow(.)/4,0))

# the first 50%:
iris %>%
  slice(1:round(nrow(.)/2,0))

# the first 75%:
iris %>%
  slice(1:round(nrow(.)/4*3,0))

# the middle 50% (i.e., after the first 25% and before the last 25%;
# the rownumbers are merely for you to check that you `slice`d the right rows:):
iris %>%
  mutate(r_num = row_number()) %>% 
  slice(round(nrow(.)/4,0):round(nrow(.)/4*3,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

In practice, you can't always get that slices of with absolute precision, as the number of rows to select must be an integer number. Therefore, it will be very common that you repeat some row in any of the sets if you aren't careful.

To obtain the first 25% of rows of a data set, namely the `iris`, you can do the following:

```
iris[1:as.integer(nrow(iris)*0.25),]
```

The `as.integer` function will give you the integer part of the float, and therefore in this way you will always left some rows, but it will guarantee that none is repeted when you select the next 50%.

If you are using tidyverse, you can do the following to get the first 25% and the next 50%.

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(pctrow = seq(1,nrow(.),1)/nrow(.)) %>% 
  filter(pctrow < 0.25)

iris %>% 
  mutate(pctrow = seq(1,nrow(.),1)/nrow(.)) %>% 
  filter(pctrow > 0.25, pctrow < 0.75)
```